# How to remove appbar more in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am currently working in Windows 10 and I am working on AppBar and Command Bar controls. I created an Appbar inside which I added a commandBar which contains and app bar button. Now the issue is it is showing more icon for both commandBar and AppBar. Can you please suggest how can I remove this?

My Code is below

```
CommandBar commandBar = new CommandBar();
if (this.BottomAppBar == null)
{
       this.BottomAppBar = new AppBar();
       this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = true;
       this.BottomAppBar.IsSticky = true;
}

commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Clear();
commandBar.IsSticky = true;
commandBar.IsOpen = true;
commandBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact;
AppBarButton appBarButton = new AppBarButton();
appBarButton.Foreground = MCSExtensions.GetColorFromHex(foreground_color);
appBarButton.Icon = new BitmapIcon() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/submit.png", UriKind.Absolute) };
appBarButton.Label = formButton.B_NAME;

commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(appBarButton);
this.BottomAppBar.Content=commandBar;
```

The above is generating following output

[image]

What I actually want is left side bar that is commandBar, not the gray portion. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong? I also tried just adding CommmandBar inside grid but it didn't display at all.

**Update**

```
CommandBar commandBar=new CommmandBar();
commandBar.IsOpen=true;
commandBar.IsSticky=true;
commandBar.ClosedDisplayMode=AppBarClosedDisplatMode.Compact;
AppBarButton appBarButton = new AppBarButton();
appBarButton.Foreground = MCSExtensions.GetColorFromHex(foreground_color);
appBarButton.Icon = new BitmapIcon() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/submit.png", UriKind.Absolute) };
appBarButton.Label = formButton.B_NAME;

commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(appBarButton);
pageLayoutRootGrid.Children.Add(commandBar);
```

I also tried adding a StackPanel in AppBar as below but not giving proper results.

```
if (this.BottomAppBar == null)
{
       this.BottomAppBar = new AppBar();
       this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = true;
       this.BottomAppBar.IsSticky = true;
}
StackPanel appBarPanel=new StackPanel();
appBarPanel.Orientation=Orientation.Horizontal;          
AppBarButton appBarButton = new AppBarButton();
appBarButton.Foreground = MCSExtensions.GetColorFromHex(foreground_color);
appBarButton.Icon = new BitmapIcon() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/submit.png", UriKind.Absolute) };
appBarButton.Label = formButton.B_NAME;

appBarPanel.Children.Add(appBarButton);
this.BottomAppBar.Content=appBarPanel;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For xaml:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept"/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

this line make your UI messed:

`this.BottomAppBar = new AppBar();`

as you can see from my xaml, create only 1 CommandBar inside BottomAppBar

Edit: if you want to use code, use this:

```
var commandBar = new CommandBar();
commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(new AppBarButton() { Label = "test" });
commandBar.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
this.root.Children.Add(commandBar);
```

**UPDATE**

Full xaml code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="CommandBarSample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CommandBarSample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="root">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();



            var commandBar = new CommandBar();
            commandBar.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            var appBarButton = new AppBarButton() { Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Accept), Label = "Accept" };
            commandBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(appBarButton);

            root.Children.Add(commandBar);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I want to create CommandBar dynamically like what I added in my question not using Xaml

Comment: root is a Grid inside Page.

<Page><Grid x:Name="root"></Grid></Page>

Comment: ok also,I am facing issue with Adpative UI in image,when I add DataTemplate in UserControl. The Text FontSize works fine but the images are not changing based on adaptive UI. Can you suggest what could be the issue?

Comment: its a difference question. Please create a new question with code sample, also is my answer for this question works for you ? If so please mark it as answer :)

Comment: This didn't help. It displayed the commandBar the way I want but when I click on more icon, then it disappears

Comment: Please post your sample so I can investigate the cause. In my sample the command bar display and work correctly.

Comment: updated my code. I am getting output proper but when I click on mode it disappears. 2nd Code works but in that icon gets hidden,when I click on more icon then it is only displayed.

Comment: I tried with my project. everything just works. I added full code sample in my answer.

Comment: The second code that I added works for me but it gets hidden under default buttons OS that appears in Lumia devices.

Comment: just react to the visibility of the virtual hard button to change margin accordingly. Its out of scope of this question

Comment: Thanks thang2410199. I debug the code and solved one mistake and it gave me perfect results.